# Connection refused error.- axios and reactjs

Tags: ajax, reactjs, authentication, axios

I have made the Login page The UI and integrate the API through the Axios library and when I hit the API it shows the error

```
xhr.js:166 OPTIONS https://testapi.halanx.com/rest-auth/login/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

URL of App UI: https://assignment-task1.herokuapp.com/

URL OF code: https://github.com/rahulkhowal/Query-Related-to-Internship-Task---Web-Development

This is the code of login

```
handleSubmit=(e)=>{
     e.preventDefault()
     //console.log("Ihi")
     const Login={
       username:this.state.email || ' ',
       password: this.state.password || ''
      }

     console.log("Login", Login);
       axios.post('http://testapi.halanx.com/rest-auth/login/', {...Login}) 

      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data); 
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =res.data;
        cookies.set('loggedIn', res.data, {path:'/'})
        this.props.history.push('Dashboard')
      })

      .catch(error =>  {
         if(!error.response){
          this.errorStatus='Error:Network Error';
         }else{
          this.errorStatus=error.respose.data.message;
         }
      })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the problem with your code. Your webserver is refusing a preflight for your POST request. Probably you are trying to call to authentication service from different domain.

Please refer to this doc.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: You should talk with your backend team for it’s resolution.

Comment: actually the backend api works well in the Postman  i think the problem is in my code just see carefully please.